# Indentation autoformat settings for backslash syntax in PyCharm/Python

Tags: python, pycharm, formatting

I often write Spark jobs with backslash line breaks, like this:

```py
result = table \
    .select(
        'a',
        'b'
    ) \
    .filter(...)
```

It's readable and beautiful.

But when I use auto-formatting in PyCharm, it breaks indentation and then the code starts to look like this:

```py
result = table \
    .select(
    'a',
    'b'
) \
    .filter(...)
```

This is unwanted to me.

Is there any way to configure auto-formatting to produce first result? I tried different combinations of  I haven't found anything.

Thanks!

The expected result is indented closing parentheses. I tried all the settings in PyCharm code style settings tab.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm's built-in formatter doesn't offer fine-grained control over this specific issue. However, you can use external formatters like [`black`](https://pypi.org/project/black/) which follow PEP 8 but are designed for better readability.

1. Install `black`: `pip install black`
2. Configure PyCharm to use `black`: `Preferences > Tools > External Tools > +`

Alternatively, you can disable auto-formatting for specific blocks of code:

```py
# fmt: off
result = table \
    .select(
        'a',
        'b'
    ) \
    .filter(...)
# fmt: on
```

This works if you're using `black` and add `# fmt: off` and `# fmt: on` around the block you don't want formatted.